# Cypress module instalation failed

Tags: npm, installation, cypress

I tried to install cypress module

> npm install cypress --save-dev

cypress.io works on Cloudflare and it blocks the request:

```
URL: https://download.cypress.io/desktop/3.4.1?platform=linux&arch=x64      
Error: Failed downloading the Cypress binary.
Response code: 403
Response message: Forbidden
```

**Is there any way to install it?**

Comment: try to remove the dev dependencies while installing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

then

```
npm install cypress --save-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

try to install it via yarn

> yarn add cypress --dev

Comment: It was the same. It was some issue with DNS probably caused by docker, because docker restart helped.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't work for me as well. I got the same error. I've created new folder in the repo.

- Run npm init -y
- Run npm install --save-dev
- Then go to
  ./node_modules/.bin/cypress open

And boom the error. I've workaround it by adding:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "cypress open"
  }
}
```

into package.json and run cypress with npm run test